# Problem with AES-128 AddRoundkey Step

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm trying to self-learn the AES-128 algorithm and ran into a snag while following these slides I found online: https://kavaliro.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/AES.pdf

For the sixth round in the example given, during the `AddRoundkey` step, the third word of the matrix after `MixColumns` (F0) is XOR-ed with the third word of the 6th `RoundKey` (B7). This apparently results in (77) which doesn't correlate with my calculation of 47. However, the process seems to proceed with this error and still gets the right ciphertext in the end (I put the ciphertext through an online decoder and got the original plaintext back).

I'm very confused as to what I am missing here?

Comment: Also posted on SO in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50264554/451475) by a different userID.

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing anything, the calculation is wrong. The calculation of the key schedule that is.

If you postulate the round calculations are correct, the round keys must be wrong, and in fact that byte of the round key is indeed wrong. Reversing the AddRoundKey calculation from the round example, the valid round key byte resulting in 0x77 is 0x87, not 0xB7.

Therefore the slide was just wrong, the values may have been entered by hand, and 8 looks like a B, so that is very likely.

Comment: This are values of round key calculated by my script: 
5468617473206d79204b756e67204675
e232fcf191129188b159e4e6d679a293
56082007c71ab18f76435569a03af7fa
d2600de7157abc686339e901c3031efb
a11202c9b468bea1d75157a01452495b
b1293b3305418592d210d232c6429b69
bd3dc2***87***b87c47156a6c9527ac2e0e4e
cc96ed1674eaaa031e863f24b2a8316a
8e51ef21fabb4522e43d7a0656954b6c
bfe2bf904559fab2a16480b4f7f1cbd8
28fddef86da4244accc0a4fe3b316f26
29c3505f571420f6402299b31a02d73a